# Windows 8.1 Recent Apps is invisible

Tags: windows-8.1, debug

So I updated from windows 8 to 8.1, and ever since, that menu that comes up with you hover the mouse in the top left of the screen (that shows your recent win8 apps) is bugged.

It shows two parts of boxes where the apps would have shown up

[image: screenshot]

and the taskbar gets a line on it where the menu should have been, and just shows the background

[image: screenshot].

Ive googled around and i don't know if its just my search query, but nothing I've gotten even remotely comes close to this.